# What is the best way to resize/crop an image on client side?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm trying to crop and resize base64 jpeg image in the browser before uploading to the server. This is done regularly on 0.5 second intervals. Currently, I'm using HTML5 canvas to do so, except for the following problems:

1- Canvas is only supported on IE versions 9 and above.

2- Each time I set Image.src ="..."; in javascript, there's about 3MB added to IE's consumed memory (shown in task manager) apparently this is a known issue. My IE version is 10.

I tried cropping and resizing the image entirely in javascript but that was incredibly slow. (I used the javascript jpeg decoder at https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs)

Given the above, what would be the best way to do this? Flash? other alternatives?
The problem with flash is that it's not supported on iphone, but I can overlook this for now. If flash is the way to go, is there any open source library to do so?

Comment: Why would you need to resize/crop image in a 0.5 second interval?

Comment: The image is a 640x480 camera snapshot sent to the server for object recognition. The image sent to the server must be scaled to a size < 10 KB for bandwidth considerations.

Comment: Is `<canvas>` really not an option then? I think using "invisible canvas" can help soothing the stress.

Comment: If by invisible canvas you mean canvas with the visible property set to 'hidden', then yes, that's what I'm doing. Again, the problem with canvas is the memory leak on IE.

Answer (score -1):

you should use php's GD2 librarie, but on server side

Comment: I have to resize on client side. The images are too big to be transmitted in original format every 0.5 sec.